# I've exported and imported all the modules perfect in but still on brower when i go to that address in url it says router does not exist

Tags: node.js, express

It is in controller folder,with file name auth.js

```
const register = async (req, res) => {
  res.send('Register User');
};

const login = async (req, res) => {
  res.send('Login User');
};

module.exports = { register, login };
```

It is in Routes folder having file name 'auth.js'

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { register, login } = require('../controllers/auth');
router.post('/register', register);
router.post('/login', login);

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the app.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
require('express-async-errors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const connectDB = require('./db/connect');
//route
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth');
const jobsRouter = require('./routes/jobs');

// error handler
const notFoundMiddleware = require('./middleware/not-found');
const errorHandlerMiddleware = require('./middleware/error-handler');

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/v1/auth', authRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/jobs', jobsRouter);
// extra packages


app.use(notFoundMiddleware);
app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    app.listen(port, () =>
      console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`)
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

I was just trying to access the register information via url in browser but at the end it just gave me error Router does not exist

Comment: Which route you're trying to visit from the browser? I don't see any route for get request in your code.